# How do i make a simple effect dropdown go up?

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu

Does anyone have a min to help me with this code?

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/11/29/simple-effects-for-drop-down-lists/

Basically, I want to have the dropdown dropup instead . . . I have tried setting

bottom: 100%;

and some other stuff, but i can't figure it out. Any thing is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us *how* you have tried to do the dropup?

Comment: Thanks for your response...I just tried to add bottom:100% to various class elements, however, I think it has to be done in the javascript...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If we could see your code we could help out better. [whathaveyoutried.com](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: post your html and css , the whole dropdown block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add or edit this css class:

```
.cd-dropdown ul {

top: auto;
bottom: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
```

if you add it make sure it's after the css file of the exemple

example using the file index.html on the provided files :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
        <title>Simple Effects for Drop-Down Lists</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Simple Effects for Drop-Down Lists" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="drop-down, select, jquery, plugin, fallback, transition, transform, 3d, css3" />
        <meta name="author" content="Codrops" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style1.css" />
        <script src="js/modernizr.custom.63321.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

<style>
.cd-dropdown ul {

top: auto;
bottom: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

you can add this snippet after the body of eache example files : index2.htnml...

or at the end of the srtyle**X**.css files
don' t forget to clear the cache of the browser!

Comment: Thank you, but that didn't work unfortunately. I tried both ways. I will try to post the code there is a ton though. it is all in the link i provided. Thanks for your help!

Comment: i have edited the post the only thing i found glitchy was the was jquery animated lthe collapse. i think this could fix it : http://jsfiddle.net/adamelevate/WFejY/

Comment: Thanks...putting the style in the head tag or beginning of the body worked as in the example above. However, it comes from the top and then bounces down it is weird. It is better than i could do though.

Comment: Cool. Thank you very much. That is a great example!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to make the `bottom: 0px;` not 100%!